# Why does Opensea split my NFT collection into two collections?

Tags: solidity, nft, testnets, rinkeby, opensea

Opensea splits my smartcontract (deploy on rinkeby) into two collections:

- https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/acoustic-treasure-gold-set-v3-1
- https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/acoustic-treasure-gold-set-v3

Both of the url's only contain NFT's that link to this smart contract:
0xEF1F9d65e91b5EdBfB78B3734a3b5D6FeADF0De2
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xef1f9d65e91b5edbfb78b3734a3b5d6feadf0de2

Does anyone know why Opensea does this? The NFT's that got split into another collection are all of them but 0, 6 and 11.
Also I did everything the same way for this collection but here it didn't split it:
https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/acoustic-treasure-gold-set-v2

There are supposed to be 41 NFT's in this collection btw.

Comment: Did you try asking their customer support?